# Django: no such table: django_session

Tags: django

I have found several topics with this title, but none of their solutions worked for me.  I have two Django sites running on my server, both through Apache using different virtualhosts on two ports fed by my Nginx frontend (using for static files).  One site uses MySql and runs just fine.  The other uses Sqlite3 and gets the error in the title.

I downloaded a copy of sqlite.exe and looked at the mysite.sqlite3 (SQLite database in this directory) file and there is indeed a django_session table with valid data in it.  I have the sqlite.exe in my system32 as well as the site-packages folder in my Python path.

Here is a section of my settings.py file:

```
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'mysite.sqlite3',         # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

I did use the python manage.py syncdb with no errors and just a "No Fixtures" comment.

Does anyone have any ideas what else might be going on here?  I'm considering just transferring everything over to my old pal MySql and just ignoring Sqlite, as really it's always given me some kind of trouble.  I was only using it for the benefit of knowing it anyway.  I have no overwhelming reason why I should use it.  But again, just for my edification does anyone know what this problem is?  I don't like to give up.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It could be that the server uses a different working directory than the `manage.py` command. Since you provide a relative path to the sqlite database, it is created in the working directory. Try it with an absolute path, e.g.:

```
'NAME': '/tmp/mysite.sqlite3',
```

Remember that you have to either run `./manage.py syncdb` again or copy your current database with the existing tables to `/tmp`.

If it resolves the error message, you can look for a better place than `/tmp` :-)

Comment: actually, I'm running on Windows XP x64 ;)  It's my home computer that's the development server.  Strangely enough, that worked when it didn't work before.  I altered the path to my Python site-packages and it created a new database file, I overwrote that file with the one I already had, and then transferred it back to the mysite folder and changed the settings.py to :

'I:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/mysite.sqlite3' in the NAME slot.  It worked for some odd reason

Comment: I say that because before I just changed the NAME to that exact thing and it didn't work.  But I guess forcing it to make a new database file, even when I just overwrote it with what I already had, woke it up somehow.

Comment: I use Benjamin solution and it works but somehow I can't do anything to my admin because my customusermodel table wasn't found. So, I try to use F_C solution and it does really works.

Answer (score 79):

After made any changes in code, run the following commands

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate
```

it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too...Although i did not had any models in my app but i guess we should still run these commands.

Answer (score 35):

run this in command shell:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This fixed for me.

Comment: worked for me since the chosen answer produces `manage.py: command not found`

Answer (score 15):

In case it helps anyone else: the problem for me was that I didn't have the `django.contrib.sessions` app uncommented in my `INSTALLED_APPS`. Uncommenting it, and rerunning a `syncdb` did the trick.

Comment: Mine too. This error is likely not related to using sqlite as a db driver.

Answer (score 15):

In my case the problem was that I forgot to run `manage.py syncdb` after I made some changes. When I did that the problem was solved.

Comment: For who needs it anno 2020, the syncdb command is now replaced with migrate since Django 1.19+. "python manage.py migrate"

Answer (score 9):

When I run "manage.py runserver". If I run when I my current path is not in project dir.(such as python /somefolder/somefolder2/currentprj/manage.py runserver) I'll got the problem like you. solve by cd to project directory before run command.

Comment: Thank you. I am running djangocms at #pythonanywhere and at the server wsgi I added
    `import os
    import sys

    path = '/home/user/project'
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

    os.chdir(path)
    from project.wsgi import application`
Hope it helps some1 else.1

Comment: If ur running it on remote server , make sure that u apply the migration once and reload the web thing in pythonanywhere

Answer (score 6):

One other possible cause can come from using:

```
./manage.py testserver
```

And then visiting the admin interface. This won't work because testserver creates a completely separate database in memory. If you want to visit the admin interface you need to use runserver.

Comment: this solve my error. there was error in my models.py. after running testserver it was detected.

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if there are pending session migrations.

> You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly
>   until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes,
>   sessions.

You can use the following command to run the migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

It happens may be beacause of undone migrations

• Executes following commands:

`python manage.py showmigrations`

`python manage.py migrate --fake your_app_name zero`

`python manage.py showmigrations`

• IF you are running on local machine, then remove file named 0001.*init*.py from migrations folder in your app

• Executes following commands:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

• then run django server:

`python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 3):

had the same issue, my resolution was to simply add 'django.contrib.comments' to INSTALLED_APPS and run `./manage.py syncdb` again.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem for admin management. After several checks, run "python manage.py migrate" without assign APP's name (get "Apply all migrations: .....), then runserver and up on the web. It worked.  I hope this could help.

Answer (score 3):

You have unapplied migrations. your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
python manage.py migrate This one worked for me.

Comment: You saved me so much headache! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have some unmigrated files.

```
Run
Python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py migrate appname
python manage.py runserver
```

But if the error still continue
The run python manage.py migrate
The run server

Answer (score 3):

In my case I only focused on different project and did not migrate the main application.

so first:

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate
```

and then to the project's:

```
manage.py makemigrations <my other project name>
manage.py migrate <my other project name>
```

Answer (score 2):

create a schema and add its name under NAME in 'databases'
run manage.py syncdb

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not getting the path of db. Just add this to your settings.py:

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#modify your db NAME as below:
'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'mysite.sqlite3'),
```

Comment: I've tweaked this a little to make it easier to read - can you check and make sure I've not changed anything that removes the meaning?

Answer (score 2):

I had made some changes in Model which was not migrated to db properly. Using the command

```
manage.py makemigrations
```

fixed my problem. I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

`syncdb` is obsolete try `python manage.py makemigrations`  and `python manage.py migrate` solved the problem ,and donot forget to add the app name is the installed app in `settings.py`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem so I ran

`heroku run ls`

and found that the `db.sqlite3` file was missing from the server.
In my case, it was because I exempted it by adding it in `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem too. **Restarting postgres and apache2 did it for me.** Makes me wonder if there was some kind of sqlite process left over which wasn't removed until you fiddled with the files or something.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in a different scenario. I am new to Django and cloned a repository from github to practice on it. The file db.sqlite3 was also copied. But there was no django_session in it. When I did

```
./manage.py showmigrations
```

.. I found out that there were some migrations. But the tables were missing in sqlite, as I never ran migrate. My issue was resolved when I ran the migrate command. Hope this helps django newbies like me.

```
./manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `'django.contrib.sessions',` line in INSTALLED_APPS

Run below commands from django shell

```
python manage.py makemigrations  #check for changes
python manage.py migrate #apply changes in DbSQLite
python manage.py syncdb #sync with database
```

django_session will appear in database with `(session_key, session_data , expire_date)`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to erase the 'sessions' entry in the django_migrations table and run makemigrations and migrate afterwards. That created the django_session table.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was that I updated `settings.py`, ran the migrations, but the systemd process was still using `SQLite` because I did not reload it. Doing `systemctl restart service_name` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

And it may be a case you are getting this error because you forget to run query python manage.py migrate before creating super user

Answer (score 1):

If you are tired of using makemigrations and migrate but the error is same  no such table django_session. Then just have a look to you code somewhere or the other you using session or calling it. Just comment the code where you are using session and then run the command makemigrations and migrate respectively. It  100% solve your issue.The cause of this error is that you deleted your migrations folder and database file that is the reason you are getting this error.Feel free to ask if problem is not solve

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/

Using database-backed sessions -

If you want to use a database-backed session, you need to add 'django.contrib.sessions' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Once you have configured your installation, run **manage.py migrate** to install the single database table that stores session data.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following command when you change on your code

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply run this commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

it's simple just run the following command

```
python ./manage.py migrate
python ./manage.py makemigrations AppName
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that's it all about migratinge.

```
python manage.py makemigrations APPNAME
```

As the answer ticked brakes when changed to a different virtual host such as windows to linux and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

run the command in the terminal or cmd prompt

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and then

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

then create superuser by setting username and password then you will be able to see the admin login page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem happened right after installing **"Debug-toolbar"** with empty models.py (with no classes), so the exact solution to my case is running those codes:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
```

that is what I want to demonstrate for this annoying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Django documentation says "Once you have configured your installation, run manage.py migrate to install the single database table that stores session data."

One possibility that i have come across is if the migration is ran for app first time before running migrations for the new project so just run migrations for the project

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

later you can run if needed

```
python manage.py makemigrations APPNAME
python manage.py migrate APPNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I deleted the existing migration files from folder with name 0001_initial.py

- Note: Don't delete any database/migrations file if you are working on live project.

2. Then deleted the db.sqlite3 database
   and ran the below 4 commands and it worked.

   ```
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
    python manage.py createsuperuser
    python manage.py runserver
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Run this command in cmd :

```
Python ./manage.py migrate --all
```

It should come on your **db**