# Django: no such table: django_session under Apache, but works with manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-admin

I am essentially getting the same error [described in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631556/django-no-such-table-django-session), but the solution doesn't work for me because I think my root cause is different.

I have my database path absolutely defined:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/var/www/myapp/database.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Still, I get the no such table: django_session.

When I run `manage.py runserver`, I do not get the error.

I have done a few other things just to try anything, but didn't help:

- manage.py reset sessions
- I deleted the db and let it get recreated with syncdb
- I tried chown apache:apache database.db and also to the parent directory chown -R apache:apache myapp/
- I tried chmod 777 database.db

My apache config looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myserver.mydomain.local
  ServerAlias myserver.mydomain.local

  DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp

  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py

  <Directory "/var/www/myapp/">
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The reason that I write /myapp twice is because the first one just contains the DB file and manage.py.  The folder under that contains the app, including wsgi.py

I also note that I must add two lines to my wsgi.py to make this run on Apache, that I do not have to add when running the app from manage.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/../"))
```

Answer (score -1):

i had the exact same error ..... mine being a windows environment.
just had to copy and place the database.db file under apache folder.
you could try doing the same and see if it helps.